# Error No module named 'django' al importarlo desde la terminal

Tags: python, django

buen día, tengo un un problema al momento de importar Django en mi terminal, no se si me puedan orientar, adjunto mi código:

```
PS C:\Users\ricar\OneDrive\Documentos\inventory> python3
Python 3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
>>> import Django

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Django'
```

Comment: Ejecuta `python -m django --version` en la terminal y fijate si esta instalado.

Comment: hola gracias, y si ya hice eso para serciorarme y si mira...

PS C:\Users\ricar\OneDrive\Documentos\inventory> pip freeze 
asgiref==3.6.0
Django==4.2
sqlparse==0.4.4
tzdata==2023.3
PS C:\Users\ricar\OneDrive\Documentos\inventory> python -m django --version
4.2

Comment: Checa las versiones de python, si tienes varias instalaciones puede ser ese el problema